# React Native Navigation 5 - How to set a color for each bottom tab

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to setup a different color for each bottom tab on RNN 5.

```
const MyTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    
<MyTab.Navigator>
  <MyTab.Screen
    name='ToTimerScreen'
    component={TimerScreen}
    options={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'Timer',
      tabBarIcon: () => TimerIcon(),
    })}
  />
  <MyTab.Screen
    name='ToJournalScreen'
    component={JournalScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Journal',
      tabBarIcon: () => JournalIcon(),
    }}
  />
</MyTab.Navigator>
```

for example one blue and one red.
I tried every possible option but no way.
Someone knows how to?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
Just use Material Bottom Tab Navigator

```
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
    
const MyTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
```

Example of a tab screen using `tabBarColor: '#color'`

```
<MyTab.Screen
  name='ToJournalScreen'
  component={JournalScreen}
  options={{
    tabBarColor: Colors.Journal, // this gives the color
    tabBarLabel: 'Journal',
    tabBarIcon: () => <Icon name={'md-book'} color={'red'} size={20} />,
  }}
/>
```

Works in Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass color props to Icon Component

```
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

const MyTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<MyTab.Navigator>
  <MyTab.Screen
        name="ToTimerScreen"
        component={TimerScreen}
        options={({route}) => ({
          tabBarLabel: 'Timer',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => <Icon name={'iconName'} color={'blue'} size={24}/>,
        })}
      />
      <MyTab.Screen
        name="ToJournalScreen"
        component={JournalScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Journal',
          tabBarIcon: () => <Icon name={'iconName'} color={'red'} size={24}/>,
        }}
      />
    </MyTab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Thanks but like this I see just the icon's color changing