# How to set two color in createMaterialTopTabNavigator tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

how can i set color1 to tab1 and color2 to tab2 in react-navigation 5 ? Here is my actual code :

```
const FavorisTop = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        safeAreaInsets: { top: 0, bottom: 0 },
      }}
      tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#5BD6C1',
        },
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'FavorisArticle'}
        component={FavorisArticles}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'ARTICLES',
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'FavorisPrestas'}
        component={FavorisPrestas}
        tabBarOptions={{
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#DBC07D',
          },
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'ARTICLES',
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

I tried setting the color in each screens but it doesn't worked.. Thanks !

**EDIT**

This the result i want :

[image]

I want to have 'Favoris' in Green and 'Prestataires' in yellow

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591670/react-native-navigation-5-how-to-set-a-color-for-each-bottom-tab

Comment: This is not working..

Comment: Can You show an image of what you are expecting as output?

Comment: Yes i will upload it !

Comment: Hey sorry to bring it back, but does someone know how to do this feature ?